# React: Can I not pass a parameter into an action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Forgive me if I'm not phrasing this right. I'm learning React now and having a problem passing a parameter into an action. Here's the action:

```
export const getPosts = filterQs => {
    return dispatch => {
        const apiUrl = wpApi.listPosts;

        if (filterQs) {
            apiUrl += "?" + filterQs;
        }

        // Actually get the posts
        dispatch(getPostsStarted());

        axios.get(`${apiUrl}`)
            .then(response => {
                dispatch(getPostsSuccess(response.data));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                dispatch(getPostsFailure(error.message));
            });
    }
}
```

The conditional containing ***if (filterQs)*** is skipped as it doesn't seem to actually have that parameter when the action is dispatched. It still returns a successful response when dispatched, it's just not including the parameter, which I need it to.

Here's where I map the dispatch in the component:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    filterUpdate,
    getPosts
}
```

And here's the method where it's actually being called.

```
changeHandler (event) {
        const checkedStatus = event.currentTarget.checked;
        const selectedTaxonomy = event.currentTarget.name;
        const termId = event.currentTarget.value;

        const paramsToSend = {
            checkedStatus: checkedStatus,
            selectedTaxonomy: selectedTaxonomy,
            termId: termId
        };

        const filterUpdatePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.props.filterUpdate(paramsToSend);
            resolve(true);
        });

        // Run the filter query string format function only after the props have updated
        filterUpdatePromise.then(() => {
            const filterQs = this.formatNewFilterQuery();
            getPosts(filterQs);
        });
    }
```

As far as I can tell, getPosts(filterQs) is being executed. If I log filterQs outside of the dispatch in the action, I actually see my parameter value in the log. I just can't figure out why I can't pass the param into the dispatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your `mapDispatchToProps` from

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    filterUpdate,
    getPosts
}
```

to

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        filterUpdate: (params) => dispatch(filterUpdate(params)),
        getPosts: (filters) => dispatch(getPosts(filters))
    }
};
```

Comment: I had tried this earlier and that didn't work, either. I just tried again and no dice.

Comment: @BryanWhite, are you able to create a minimum minimal reproducible example over at https://codesandbox.io/s/new You can add Redux to a React project and create a fake API call. It makes it easier to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: I can't because it relies on a wordpress custom post type and three custom taxonomies that only exist locally BUT! I do have this in a github repo if that helps at all. https://github.com/TheeBryanWhite/wpreact-resource-center

Comment: @BryanWhite, one thing I just noticed is that when you call `getPosts(filterQs);`, you are not calling your function through your dispatcher by doing `this.props.getPosts(filterQs);`. You do that here though, `this.props.filterUpdate(paramsToSend);`.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I updated the code and now it works. Thanks for talking this out with me.